# Rounding values in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `values` as shown below

```
January  February  March
0.02345  0.03456   0.04567
0.05432  0.06543   0.07654
```

I need a command to round each of these values to 3 decimal points.
Output should be as shown below

```
January  February  March
0.023    0.035     0.046
0.054    0.065     0.077
```

Comment: Are you looking for rounding or formatting, in example 0.02345 would round to 0.024, not 0.023

Comment: Or `options(digits = 2)`

Comment: actually any rounding is fine with me

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In case your data frame contains non-numeric characters you may be willing to make use of the function by [Jeromy Anglim](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/50228877196/round-numbers-in-data-frame-that-contains-non):

```
round_df <- function(x, digits) {
    # round all numeric variables
    # x: data frame 
    # digits: number of digits to round
    numeric_columns <- sapply(x, mode) == 'numeric'
    x[numeric_columns] <-  round(x[numeric_columns], digits)
    x
}

round_df(data, 3)
```

I think it's neat and quick approach to handle the rounding problem across heterogeneous data frames.

Comment: I'm curious why one would do this when there is `format.data.frame`. Can you describe any potential advantages?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 Try `format.data.frame(mtcars, digits = 1)$mpg + 1` and `round_df(mtcars, digits = 1)$mpg + 1`.

Comment: this no longer works...

Comment: @CyrusMohammadian could you post a reprex?

Comment: `round_df(iris, 3)` `Error in Math.data.frame(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5,  : 
  non-numeric variable(s) in data frame: Species`

Comment: This did not work for me on data frames with character and numeric columns. 
I added a clause to resolve the issues. 
```r
round_df <- function(x, digits) {
    # round all numeric variables
    # x: data frame 
    # digits: number of digits to round
    # select all numeric columns 
    for(i in 1:ncol(x)){
      if(class(x[,i])=="numeric"){
        x[i] <-  round(x[i], digits)
      }
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As indicated by @DavidArenburg, you can also use `options`. This can be done either globally or via `print`. I generally prefer the latter if it's just for rendering a single `data.frame` where I don't want to actually lose the original (raw) data.

Example:

```
## Sample data frame
mydf <- data.frame(January = c(0.02345, 0.05432), February = c(0.03456, 0.06543), 
                   March = c(0.04567, 0.07654), non_numeric = c("abcdefgh", "ijklmno"))
mydf
#   January February   March non_numeric
# 1 0.02345  0.03456 0.04567    abcdefgh
# 2 0.05432  0.06543 0.07654     ijklmno
```

Here, we use the `digits` argument in `print`:

```
print(mydf, digits = 2)
#   January February March non_numeric
# 1   0.023    0.035 0.046    abcdefgh
# 2   0.054    0.065 0.077     ijklmno
```

This is the same as if we had used `format` (which has a default method for `data.frame`s. See `?format.data.frame` for more information on the options).

```
format(mydf, digits = 2)
```

Alternatively, as recommended by @David:

```
## Setting `options`:
options(digits = 2)
mydf
#   January February March non_numeric
# 1   0.023    0.035 0.046    abcdefgh
# 2   0.054    0.065 0.077     ijklmno
options(digits = 7) ## Reset default options
```